# second order exact differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable, integrating-factor

I'm stuck in trying to solve the following ODE:

$$y'' + 4xy' + (2+4x^2)y = 0$$

I tried finding an **integration factor** as if it was exact but I have not succeed. I also tried by trying to get rid of the $y'$-term* yet I ended up with another, still 2nd order equation unable to solve by myself.

*NOTE: I tried with the CV: $y = vY$, where $\displaystyle Y = exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\int p(x)\mathrm{d}x\right]$

Is there any way or trick you use to deal with this?

If you have any other method or a specific way to approach/categorize ODEs it would be awesome to learn from you guys. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'' + (4x)y' + (2+4x^2)y = 0$$
Integrating factor is $\mu (x) =e^{x^2}$
$$e^{x^2}(y'' + 2xy') +e^{x^2}(2xy' +(2+4x^2)y) = 0$$
$$(e^{x^2}y')'  +(2xe^{x^2}y)'=0$$
Integrate:

$$e^{x^2}y' +2xe^{x^2}y=K_1$$
Integrate again :
$$(ye^{x^2})'=K \implies ye^{x^2}=K_1x+K_2$$
$$y(x)=e^{-x^2}(K_1x+K_2)$$

Comment: Is there any particular way to find such integrating factor or see what it might approximately look like maybe? Good vision. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well Paul I don't know any formula that might give you an integrating factor for a second ordre linear equation. Sometimes you guess a functios like $x^m, e^x$. Function like that than you try to understand what you could change to make the technique of the integrating factor work. Most of the time this kind of equations can't be solved. Except particular second linear equation. (Euler, Legendre ...).